# Anchors are not working on mobile device in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile, navigation, anchor

I have a site:

https://fehergallerosvillanyszerelo.hu/

it worked just fine, and now I experienced that my navigation crashes on mobile devices in Chrome (in FF it work fine). Better said, it works sometimes, then it does not work. The code is very easy and this is not my first site. Do you have any idea, what is wrong?

This is the menu structure:

```
<li class="nav-item kapcsolatFelvetel">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#kapcsolatFelvetel">Kapcsolatfelvétel</a>
</li>
```

and its target

```
<div class="container-fluid py-5 position-relative section" id="kapcsolatFelvetel">
    ...
</div>
```

I already tried to set ID lowercase, changed the link to `<div id=...>` method to the old fashioned `<a name=...>` method, but did not help.

I do not have further idea, what is wrong, I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.